# how to check in flask whether a variable parameter is passed in url or not?

Tags: python, flask, rest, dynamic-url

for example the url is : `http://localhost:5000/create/user/<int:id>`

I want to check whether the user has passed the **id** parameter or not.

I have done this.

```
@app.route('/create/user/<int:id>')
def create_user(id=None):
    if id is None:
         return jsonify({'message':'Bad request'})
```

for example

1. `http://localhost:5000/create/user/23`
2. `http://localhost:5000/create/user/`

In the **1** url the user has provided the value of id=23 so we will procedd but in the url **2**, the user has not provided any value for **id** parameter, so we will throw some kind of error.

I want to know, how to implement such functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In variable `w` will be stored `Boolean value` of your desired check.

```
url = http://localhost:5000/create/user/1234
id = 1234
w = str(id) in ''.join(url.split('http://localhost:5000/create/user/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a positive look behind with a regex to do this:

```
(?<=user\/)\d+
```

This matches any number of digits preceeded by `user/`.